# My SKSprite node is showing up as just a black box

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to add a enemy to my scene, but when I do so, the sprite just shows up as a black box. I know I have the right image in the project and everything because it was working in the GameScene class. However, I wanted to move it to another class so I could add multiple enemies.

Here is the code in the Enemy class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: size)
    }

    convenience init(pos: CGPoint) {
        let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")
        self.init(texture: monster.texture, color: monster.color, size: monster.size)
        self.position = pos
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
        self.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
        self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
        self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And here is how I called it in my GameScene class:

```
    let monster = Enemy(pos: CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.7, y: size.height * 0.7))
    addChild(monster)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
 override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: size)
    }
```

to:

```
 override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: size)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new SKSpriteNode using an image:

```
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")
```

And right after that, you are re-initializing it with its own data (but as Basher_CAD pointed out, you're ignoring the texture, as well as the color):

```
    self.init(texture: monster.texture, color: monster.color, size: monster.size)
```

Removing the `self.init` call (and the method as well) should resolve the issue.